# Consolidate annotations on a zoomed MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, annotations, mkmapview

There are a number of bad ways to go about what I want to do, but this seems like one of those cases of "there must be a better way".

I am using an MKMapView in an iPhone app that displays a number of annotations. Pretend for conceptual discussion that each town in a US state has an annotation, so there's a fairly dense pile of annotations onscreen. As the user zooms out the map, those annotations start to crunch in on one another, until they are overlapping and become hard to pick out individually.

What I'd like to do is, at a particular density of annotations (say when any annotations overlap), consolidate those annotations into a single annotation that indicates it encloses a number of sub-annotations (some visual indicator to say, "zoom in and you'll see more annotations").

I could call CGRectIntersectsRect on the annotation views, but using that would appear to be an N^2 problem -- I would have to iterate over each annotation *for each annotation*. Consider this pseudocode:

```
FOR firstAnnotationView IN allAnnotationViews
   FOR secondAnnotationView in allAnnotationViews
       IF CGRectIntersectsRect(firstAnnotationView.frame, secondAnnotationView.frame)
           // found two overlapping annotations, consolidate them
       ENDIF
   ENDFOR
ENDFOR
```

You can see why that would be slow, and it would have to run every time the map was zoomed in or out!

So how would you all detect overlapping annotations in the map, and in a performance-savvy fashion, consolidate them intelligently?

Comment: Consider your search space.  Is it necessary to consider all annotations in your outer loop?  What about simply evaluating the annotations currently in view?

Answer (score 1):

I would bin your annotations based on longitude/latitude and then consolidate using those bins.  The basic idea would look something like this:

```
#include <vector>

float minLongitude = 180.0f;
float maxLongitude = -180.0f;
float longitudeBinSize = 0.1; // Degrees
float minLatitude = -90.0f;
float maxLatitude = 90.0f;
float latitudeBinSize = 0.1; // Degrees
int numBinColumns = int((maxLongitude - minLongitude) / longitudeBinSize);
int numBinRows = int((maxLatitude - minLatitude) / latitudeBinSize);

void calcBinCoords(float longitude, float latitude, int &column, int &row) {
    column = int((latitude - minLatitude) / latitudeBinSize);
    row = int((longitude - minLongitude) / longitudeBinSize);
}

typedef std::vector<AnnotationView *> AnnotationViews;

void binAnnotations(NSArray *annotationViews, std::vector<AnnotationViews> &binnedAnnotations) {
    binnedAnnotations.clear();
    binnedAnnotations.resize(numBinColumns * numBinRows);
    for (AnnotationView *annotationView in annotationViews) {
        int column, row;
        calcBinCoords(annotationView.longitude, annotationView.latitude, column, row);
        binnedAnnotations[row * numBinColumns + column].push_back(annotationView);
    }
}
```

The values for longitudeBinSize and latitudeBinSize would be the maximum distance that you intend to search when consolidating.  Once everything is in bins then your search problem only involves searching the list of values in adjacent bins for candidates.  Also, since you'll be scanning the array during consolidation you really only need to check three of the adjacent bins for each bin you process -- the bin at (column+1,row), the bin at (column,row+1), and the bin at (column+1,row+1).

You could use NSMutableArrays instead of std::vector for the bins, but it sounds like you have a large number of items to process and I suspect std::vector will be faster.  That's just my preference though, it may not matter enough to even care.  If you use ObjC instead of ObjC++ then you can't use std::vector of course.

Answer (score 1):

you search for something like this, aren't you?

http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtclustermaker/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) to partition your annotations. This would reduce the search space when trying to "consolidate" your annotations.