# Mapkit with multiple annotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mapkit, ios4

I have a map displaying multiple annotations.
I'd like to mimic the behavior of the Places tab on the Photos built-in app (iOS 4), where the annotations are automatically joined together or splited apart as the user changes the zoom level.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many similar/duplicate questions like this: Try searching for 'consolidating annotations' or 'group annotations'

Comment: Your suggestion came up with these 2 discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194646/how-can-i-group-mkannotations-automatically-regarding-zoom-level and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589891/consolidate-annotations-on-a-zoomed-mkmapview . As you can see they are basically the same question but got no helpful idea. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific clustering functionality that is used in the 'Places' feature of The Photos app is not exposed to developers currently. If your are looking for a magic library, sample code or the like to do this currently you are out of luck.

If you are very comfortable with MapKit and clustering techniques in general you could work on rolling your own solution or contributing to a public effort to achieve this.

Some things to look at:

[iPhone Map Kit cluster pinpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047691/iphone-map-kit-cluster-pinpoints)
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html